# standardizing a value, iterating over a groupby object

Tags: python, iteration, pandas-groupby

I need some help iterating over a groupby object in python. I have people nested under a single ID variable, and then under each one of those, they have balances for anywhere from 3 to 6 months. So, printing the groupby object looks, for example, like this:

```
(1,    Primary BP     Product Rpt Month Closing Balance
0      1  CHECK    201708          10.04
1      1  CHECK    201709           11.1
2      1  CHECK    201710          11.16
3      1  CHECK    201711          11.22
4      1  CHECK    201712          11.28
5      1  CHECK    201801          11.34)
(2,      Primary BP     Product Rpt Month Closing Balance
79       2  CHECK    201711        52.42
85       2  CHECK    201712        31.56
136      2  CHECK    201801          99.91)
```

I want to create another column that standardizes the closing balance based on their first amount. So the ideal output would then look like this:

```
(1,    Primary BP     Product Rpt Month Closing Balance standardized
0      1  CHECK    201708          10.04    0
1      1  CHECK    201709           11.1    1.1
2      1  CHECK    201710          11.16    1.16
3      1  CHECK    201711          11.22    1.22
4      1  CHECK    201712          11.28    1.28
5      1  CHECK    201801          11.34    1.34)
(2,      Primary BP     Product Rpt Month Closing Balance standardized
79       2  CHECK    201711        52.42      0
85       2  CHECK    201712        31.56    -20.86
136      2  CHECK    201801          99.91   47.79)
```

I just can't quite figure out how to make a nice for loop, or if there is any other way, that will iterate within the groups of a groupby object, taking the first value for closing balance and subtracting it from each closing balance to essentially create a difference score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Only two weeks later. Did it without the use of a groupby object. Here is how:

```
bpid = []
diffs = []

# These two lines were just a bit of cleaning needed to make the vals numeric
data['Closing Balance'] = data['Closing Balance'].str.replace(",", "")
data['Closing Balance'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Closing Balance'])

# Create a new variable in monthly_data that simply shows the increase in closing balance for each month,
# setting the first month to 0
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    bp = row[0]
    if bp not in bpid:
        bpid.append(bp)
        first = row[3]
    bal = row[3]
    diff = round(bal-first, 2)
    diffs.append(diff)
    row['balance increase'] = diff

# Just checking to make sure there are the right number of values. Same as data, so good to go
print(len(diffs))

# Convert my list of differences in closing balance to a series object, and merge with the monthly_data
se = pd.Series(diffs)
data['balance increase'] = se.values
```